# How to prevent form from resetting after returning no results?

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, html-select

I've been mocking up a mysql & php searching page, which is functioning as expected. But, when the form is POSTed **and returns no results**, the `<option>` tags are reset, i was wondering whether i could prevent this from happening?

**META**: I'm aware of the deprecation of `mysql_*` and the posibilities of mySQL injections, this is just a quick mockup.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect');
mysql_select_db("webhost") or die ('Could not find DB');
$output = '';

// Queries 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $dsquery = $_POST['Diskspace'];
    $prquery = $_POST['Price'];

    $query =  mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM data WHERE Diskspace BETWEEN $dsquery
    AND Price BETWEEN $prquery 
    ") ;
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($count == 0){
        $output = "No such results, sorry.";
    }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $diskspace = $row['Diskspace'];
            $price = $row['Price'];
            $host = $row['Provider'];
            $output .= '<div>'.$host.'  '.$diskspace.'  '.$price.'</div>'; 
        }
    }
    print ("$output");
} 

 ?>
```

Comment: may be you could use ajax to submit the form

Comment: Is the form on the same page as the php code above?

Comment: Not enough codes to know the problem

Comment: @MichaelGarrison, That's correct Michael, it's on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AJAJ/AJAX. That's one way of retaining form data.

There are many jQuery features like .post & .ajax to do this.

You could also create an Object and store post data.

You could also use sessions.

Comment: How would i implement this?

Comment: Google : jQuery form data php

Comment: use jquery $.ajax() or $.post() functions

Comment: I thought of sessions, but, how would sessions affect the URLs?

Comment: Sessions are fine but not recommend by me .

Comment: Can i ask you why you wouldn't recommend it? UPDATE: I'll follow this video for AJAX data forms - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yb3c-HljFro

Comment: Because there are better ways like jQuery.